# Determine module file location

Tags: lua

after loading a module in Lua, I'd like to determine what module file this corresponds to. In python, you do this with code like:

```
import module_name
module_name.__file__
```

So in Lua if I do something like

```
require 'math'
```

what do I put next to determine where this module is located? Btw, I don't actually need the location of math, but instead have some other third-party packages that were downloaded and want to know what copy of the build files are actually being used when I invoke Lua.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `package` library might give you what you need.

For instance, if I have `util.lua` in my Lua path such that I can write:

```
require 'util'
```

I can get the path to the file like this:

```
print(package.searchpath('util', package.path))
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried this with 'math' and got the following result:         `Lua 5.2.0  Copyright (C) 1994-2011 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> require 'package'
> require 'math'
> print(package.searchpath('math',package.path))
nil 
 no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/math.lua'
 no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.2/math/init.lua'
 no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/math.lua'
 no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.2/math/init.lua'
 no file './math.lua'
 no file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/math.lua'
 no file '/usr/share/lua/5.2/math/init.lua'
 no file './math.lua'`
Is that the expected result? Seems odd that it says "no file" everwhere.

Comment: Also, sorry that the above looks so terrible, guess I can't do newlines in the comments...

Comment: @gammapoint: 'math' is not a normal package. It's a [package that's part of Lua](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.6). It doesn't have a location; it's pre-loaded. It's an internal module. Try it with an external module.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thanks for the clarification Nicol. I'm going to mark this as the answer because I'm betting it works for most external modules in Lua. It doesn't actually work for me for the package I'm interested in doing it with ('nn' in Torch7) but that might be because I'm not running Lua per-se, but rather Torch7, which is somehow based upon Lua (most Lua syntax is valid). Thanks for the solution though; I'm sure I'll use it in the future.

Comment: In lua 5.1 `package.searchpath` doesn't exist.